# finding $\lim_{x \to \infty}x^2\ln x$

Tags: calculus, limits

> finding $\lim_{x \to \infty}x^2\ln x$

What I thought is that $x^2\gg \ln x$ therefore $\lim_{x \to \infty}x^2\ln x=\infty$

looking at [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20x%20to%20infinty%20x%5E2lnx) its multiply the limit $\infty \times \infty=\infty$

Is my way ok? Are there arithmetic laws of limits when both function are $\infty$ or $-\infty$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both functions are unbounded and strictly positive for large enough $x$ so of course their product should be unbounded and strictly positive for large enough $x$. If you are uncomfortable with this sort of reasoning, you could make a simple algebraic manipulation:

$$ x^2 \log (x) = \log (x^{x^2})$$

Now you have a single function which you know is unbounded as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: what about the same just when $x\to 0$?

Comment: Good question. As $x \to 0$, you now have to use different reasoning because you know $x^2 \to 0$ but $log(x) \to -\infty$, so this reasoning breaks down. In that case, you can consider L'Hospital or Taylor series.

Comment: to use L'Hospital I have to get to expression of $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

Comment: Right, use the trick where you write one of the factors, such as $x^2$ as $\frac{1}{x^2}^{-1}$.

Comment: is it ok to write $lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{lnx}{x^2}$ and use L'Hospital?

Comment: $x^2 \log (x) = \frac{1}{x^{-2}} \log (x) = \frac{\log (x) } {1/x^2}$ and now apply L'Hospital.

Answer (score 1):

This limit is bounded below by $x^2$ when $x \geq e$, and $\log x$ when $x > 1$. Both functions are known to diverge.